# getting facebook Access token from java app

Tags: java, facebook-access-token

I am working on a java desktop app in which I can access Facebook Info. By copying and pasting the Access Token in my code for testing purpose, this works great. But My problem is getting that Access Token when the log-in button is pressed in the java app, with the chance of the user redirected to the Facebook log-in page or the App Authorization page to grant the app Access. I have tried using Javascript too but it can't return the access token to the java desktop app.
thank you